# How can I edit or add to a particular field without pull the all object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

1. How I can do just this ( `a.myFavorits.Add()`) without pulling the all object to var `a` , because `a` has a lot of data, and I don't want to pull all `a` object, but I can't find a way do do it.
2. I want to do the lambada and the linq without return something but linq is always return something

   ```
   public static void addFavorits(long f,long idUser)
   {
       using (var db = dataBase())
       {
          // here i pull object user from users table
           var a = db.users.Where(c => c.id == idUser).SingleOrDefault();

          // here i adding  to the object field  myFavorits new value
           //myFavorits is also a table of entitys that connected to user object

           a.myFavorits.Add(new BE.FavoritsUsersLong { myLong = f });

            db.SaveChanges(); 
       }
   }
   ```

I thought to do something like this but i dont know how to set the field `users_TableId`  that is the key that connect the 2 tables

```
public static void addFavorits(long favoritId,long idUser)
{
    using (var db = dataBase())
    {
        db.favoritsUsersLong.Add(new BE.FavoritsUsersLong {myLong = favoritId} 
               /*,users_TableId =idUser*/);

        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean the all object?  it looks like you are querying for a particular user and adding a favorite.  What's the issue?

Comment: when i pull object user from users table into a, i get the all object , the object contain a lot of fields with data, beside the field myFavorits, why i need to pull all object when i want to update one field

Answer (score 2):

Here's a concrete example that does what you want. In this example, only the `Name` of a `Company` is modified and saved. Or an item is added to one of its collections.

```
var cmp = new Company{ CmpId = 1, Name = "Cmp1" }; // CmpId is the primary key
db.Companies.Attach(cmp);
db.Entry(cmp).Property(c => c.Name).IsModified = true;

// Or add an entity to a collection:
cmp.Users = new[] {new User { Name = "a1", PassWord = "a1" } };

try
{
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
finally
{
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
}
```

Result in SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @0 VarChar(30) = 'Cmp1'
DECLARE @1 Int = 1
UPDATE [dbo].[Company]
SET [Name] = @0
WHERE ([CmpId] = @1)
```

There are a few things to note here:

- Obviously you need to know the Id of the entity you want to modify.
- The object you create is called a *stub entity*, which is an incomplete entity. When you try to save such an entity, EF is very likely to complain about null values in required properties. That's why almost certain you'd have to disable validation (temporarily, or, better, dispose the context immediately).
- If you want to add an item to a collection, you should leave validation enabled, because you'd want to know for sure that the new entity is valid. So you shouldn't mix these two ways to use a stub entity.
- If you often need roughly the same small part of your entity you may consider [table splitting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.8).

Comment: i dont understand how does the new BE.FavoritsUsersLong { myLong = f },at your example  cmp will add to entity in users in table users that connect to table FavoritsUsersLong

Comment: I still have trouble understanding your answer, take a look at the second part I added, that's exactly what I want to do in a shorter way

Comment: Well, apparently, `FavoritsUsersLong` doesn't have this property `users_TableId`. So you could create a stub `User` object (it that's the object you don't want to fetch), and add a `FavoritsUsersLong` to its collection, *or* you could add `users_TableId` to `FavoritsUsersLong`.

Comment: FavoritsUsersLong  have the property users_TableId , i wrote it with text editor because the table is a little different, but i dont know how to set the value because the users_TableId exist in the table FavoritsUsersLong  but not in the object BE.FavoritsUsersLong, becasue its a key that say this line belong to some object in users table

Comment: You probably mean that the *database table* has the *column* users_TableId, but the *class* (BE.FavoritsUsersLong) doesn't have the *property*. If so, as I said, add the property, or use a stub `User`. If not, I'm afraid I can't follow you.

Comment: i cant add users_TableId to (BE.FavoritsUsersLong) because i get exception The model backing the 'usersDB' context has changed , and if i create the database again i get 2 columns in FavoritsUsersLong  table that called users_TableId , users_TableId1

Comment: OK, this is diverting into a different issue. I think I've given you some viable options. If you want you can ask a new question about the migration issue emerging now, after doing due diligence to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you want?  I don't see you 'editting' I only see you adding.

```
using (var db = dataBase())
{
    var a = new user(); 
     .... 
     //set properties etc..
     ...
    a.myFavorits.Add(new BE.FavoritsUsersLong { myLong = f });
    db.users.Add(a);
    db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: and how the new BE.FavoritsUsersLong will be connected to the user object?, you created new user, i want edit exist user